# How to know whether a model is new or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

post = Post.new
```

How do I judge whether the 'post' is a new model which is not pulled from the database?

Comment: Please use 4 spaces indent to mark text as code.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
post.new_record?
```

Answer (score 40):

ActiveRecord's `new_record?` method returns `true` if the object hasn't been saved yet.

- [new_record? documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001843)

Comment: new_record? is note listed in the linked documentation
I believe you meant this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html

Comment: @jcarlson Look at when I posted my answer and consider that the documentation may have changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 10):

you can use post.persisted? as well, if it return false means record in new

[persisted?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F)

Comment: This is more straight forward, because with `new_record?` you'll need to test for `false` to know if your record has saved. Kinda backward logic in my mind, but to each their own!

Comment: From the link provided a comment by `hosh`: "`new_record?` will not check if the record has been destroyed." So I guess this is something to take note of if you are checking for record destroyed.